# Full Website Within Chrome Application Window

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app

Was wondering if I had a web-application on www.mydomain.com/userportal etc but didn't want this accessable via the browser, but as a chrome application similar to how Google's Hangouts is a seperate window / popup - How easy is it to implement an already built application into one of these windows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to display your www site as a Chrome App. Chrome apps are all HTML/CSS/JS files hosted on the computer but they can display a webview into a site online. However, Chrome Apps must be 'offline' first. So you must ask for permissions to all online activity.

Ideally you would make separate app hosted as a Chrome App (not link/embedded to a www site) that uses an API to talk to a web-app.

Keep in mind that Google is phasing out Chrome Apps for all platforms except Chrome OS in the near future.